# Magnetic Attraction in Space

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, space, perpetual-motion

If I were to attach a 1 inch diameter magnet to lets say a half pipe, that it fits perfectly in, and attach a 1 in diameter piece of iron close enough for the magnet to assert its attractive pull, would the magnet end up pulling the entire contraption in space and move.  If so, would the acceleration increase exponentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, because there is only an attractive force between the magnet and the iron, but the combined system of magnet, iron and pipe has no change in its net momentum, since there is no external force.

If the entire system would accelerate, it would gain momentum and kinetic energy without an external force. But since momentum and energy are conserved, this is impossible.

Let's look at the individual forces acting*:

1. The magnet acts on the iron with a force $F$
2. The iron acts on the magnet with a force $-F$

Both forces cancel each other out to exactly $0$.

*I assume the pipe to be infinitely rigid.

Comment: I'm still confused…in a zero gravity environment why would the magnet not exert and attractive force on the iron, whose pull would exert a force on the pipe its attached to and move it towards the magnet.

Comment: Because the Iron also attracts the magnet and so these forces cancel each other out with respect to the whole system.

Comment: I deleted an inappropriate comment. @Jody please keep in mind that that sort of thing is not appropriate here.